# Ссылка на скачивание файла .txt и .pdf

Tags: файлы, html

Как сделать, чтобы скачивался а не открывался в браузере?

Comment: download="" мр3 скачивает

Answer (score 10, accepted):

грубо говоря так:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"1.pdf\"");
$x = fread(fopen("1.pdf", "rb"), filesize("1.pdf"));
echo $x;
```

Еще есть такой совет для вебсерверов с поддержкой .htaccess, но я не пробовал:
  htaccess - простой файл конфигурации, который позволяет изменять конфигурацию веб-сервера на стороне веб мастера. Именно он помогает обходить те запреты, которые устанавливает хостер, так как сам конфигурационный файл хостер не предоставляет в редактирование, но зато дает возможность управлять параметрами веб сервера при помощи .htaccess

В который необходимо добавить запись в виде.

AddType application/download .pdf
или в зависимости от того как будет происходить сохранение файла
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
или
AddType application/force-download  .pdf

После этого все файлы в формате pdf будут именно скачиваться на ваш компьютер, а не открываться в браузере.

либо странный способ:

Так же можно в ссылку вставить download=""

```
<a href="1.pdf" target="_blank" download="">Скачать PDF</a>
```

Comment: download="" работает! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Создаем файл download.php туда вставляем код ниже, сохраняем, закидываем в папку где у нас страница и на странице пишем:

```
    <a href="dowloads.php?file=скачиваемый файл">Файл который можно скачать</a>
```

Код в dowloads.php:

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    header("Content-type: application/x-download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    readfile($filename);
} else { header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"); echo '404 Not Found'; }
?>
```

Как то так.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню, то через HTML - никак. Но вообще со стороны сервера можно content-type поменять, чтобы файл наверняка скачивался...

Comment: А на php как?